# Клик по кнопке с PhantomJS

Tags: вконтакте, selenium, phantomjs

Здравствуйте, использую PhantomJS совместно c Visual Studio на C#.
Была поставлена задача авторизации Вконтакте, переходе на какой-нибудь паблик и подписаться на него.
Все было отлично, до того как я начал нажимать на кнопку "Подписаться".
Что только ни пробовал, и по Xpath, по Selector, по Id, через Javascript через querySelector, через всевозможные конструкции нажатия на кнопку.
Никак. Просто никак. Кнопку находит всегда, ошибок никаких нет, но клик не происходит, то есть он может и есть, но нет результата. Бьюсь уже третий день подряд, не знаю, может быть это защита контакта от фантома. На chromedriver все работает, все кликает. На фантоме никак, в группы подписывается, а в паблики никак не хочет. Помогите пожалуйста. Прилагаю код

```
        IJavaScriptExecutor JS = Browser as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://vk.com/publicgames");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        JS.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('#public_subscribe').click;");
```

Comment: Может chrome headless использовать, фантом умирает.

Если не тайна, то скажите, что вы хотите тестировать?

Comment: Хотел вообще разобраться в автоматизации некоторых действий в интернете. Спасибо большое, headless chrome очень помог, раньше не знал как его запускать

Answer (score 0):

Задача решена с помощью режима headless с chromedriver.

```
   ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
    option.AddArgument("--headless");
    Browser = new ChromeDriver(driverService, option);
```